# Custom Image Handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6, asp.net-4.0

I've got a custom image handler (.ashx) which extends IHttpHandler. Basically all it does is fetch some images from a database and make them a thumbnail if requested.

This works fine on my local machine, but when I deploy it to my IIS 6 web server my images don't display.

My question is - can anyone tell me what the procedure is for setting up a handler like this in IIS 6?

**Update**

The paths to my image (that don't display) look like this:

> http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/Helpers/ImageHandler.ashx?imageid=7&thumbnail=1

I've added this to my web.config file, but still no luck:

```
<httpHandlers> <add verb="*.png" path="MyWeb.Helpers.ImageHandler" type="MyWeb.Helpers.ImageHandler, MyWeb"/> </httpHandlers>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need configure IIS6 to map the mime types to be parsed by .NET, so that they can be called by your handler; there is more on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx).

EDIT

Also try adding this to your web.config;

```
<add verb="*" path="*.png" type="MyWeb.Helpers.ImageHandler, MyWeb.Helpers"/>
```

Hope this helps,

Matt

Comment: So if I've configured png files to be handled by aspnet_isapi.dll in IIS 6, this should work? Do I need to make any changes to my web.config file?

Comment: @JimmyC I have added the relevant config setting to my solution; I hope this helps.